# How to turn these camera properties into standard calibration?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera

I have a product of a long closed company whose camera properties i need to figure out. I have the following info about the camera (e.g. FOV), and wonder how i turn this into standard
camera calibration parameters (focal length + principal point) so that i can construct a camera matrix that i can use with openCV. (NB: there are also radial and tangential distortion parameters, but i left those out of the listing below as they're obvious)

```
## SceneCamWidth:   1280
## SceneCamHeight:  960
## SceneCamFOV: 58.410146519580450785724679008126
## SceneCamDistortionModel: None
## SceneCamSensorOffsetX:   -6.82891845703125
## SceneCamSensorOffsetY:   4.581512451171875
## SceneCamPixelPitchX: 0.00375
## SceneCamPixelPitchY: 0.00375
## SceneCamPos: 0   10.5    12.5
## SceneCamOrX: 10.06933620662360873154739238089
## SceneCamOrY: 0.5876239088537422716740366013255
## SceneCamOrZ: -0.023156037041591612940516498042598
```

I can run a camera calibration myself to verify the outcome of the conversion (I assume calibrations are pretty repeatable), but i need to figure out what the above means to write a script that others can use without having to calibrate their camera.

Comment: It is necessary to present not only the parameter values but also your camera model (equation) .

Comment: @fana: part of my problem is that i do not know what camera model they are using. I am assuming pinhole.

Comment: If you don't know the meaning of those values, what you can try will become to "assume and confirm".
Assume the meaning of each parameter and use the actual taken data to check whether the pinhole camera model based on the assumption is appropriate.

Comment: For example, "SceneCamSensorOffsetX may be an offset from the center of the image of the principal point, and the unit may be pixel"

Comment: @fana: thanks. Thats indeed what i'll have to resort to indeed. Good to know it doesn't seem to be some alternative standard that i failed to find out about.

Comment: @fana, this worked out indeed. Values calculated with those assumptions came out close to my own calibration. Thanks